# HTTP 'Get' Security

Tags: http, get

What are some HTTP 'Get' Security best practices?

When should HTTP Get querystring values be obscured?

**Edit** - The application I've inherited has all of the querystring parameters XOR 'encrypted'.  It also passes things like AccountID in the querystring.  So I'm wondering if these are good practices and how I would go about correcting these things if they aren't.

**Edit** -

One method I could use to solve this would be to create a base class (this is just pseudo code):

```
public mustinherit class QSBase

  public shared Unique as long = 0
  private m_ID as string

  public readonly property ID
    get
      return m_ID
    end get
  end property

  public sub new()
   m_ID = Unique 'somehow get a unique value for this querystring
   Unique += 1
  end sub

  public function IDQueryString() as string
    return "ID=" & m_ID
  end function

end class
```

Then for each page in application I would create a derived class with properties for each query string value.

```
public class QSPage1
  inherits QSBase

  private m_AccountID as string

  public readonly property AccountID as string
    get
      return m_AccountID
    end get
  end property

  public sub new(byval _AccountID as string)
    m_AccountID = _AccountID
  end sub

end class
```

Then when I pass the query string to popups or other pages I instance the relevant class, store it in the session and pass the unique id on the query string

```
Dim qs as new QSPage1("123456")
Session(qs.ID) = qs
Server.Transfer("Page1.aspx?" & qs.IDQueryString())
'or
CreatePopup("Page1.aspx?" & qs.IDQueryString())
```

Within the page I access the values by pulling the unique ID and referencing the stored session value:

```
AccountID = CType(Session(Request.QueryString("ID")), QSPage1).AccountID()
```

Of course that can be put into a function or a class in the page.

Some benefits of this approach are:

- None of the query string is visible except an unrelated ID.
- It's fairly easy to implement in already existing code.

Some of the drawbacks are that:

- A long session could accumulate many of these querystring objects
- The unique ID would need to be "truly unique" for that session

Can anyone think of any other benefits/drawback or a better way to do this (besides rewriting the application)?

**Edit** -

Thanks to all who say to use HTTPS and POST.  Unfortunately, I'm looking for answers that have to do with using 'GET' only.  (Unless you can explain how to post data to popups without using the QueryString, Session or Javascript? )

Comment: Out of curiosity, what kind of information do you think should be obscured?

Comment: This question sounds very generic too me. What do you want to secure? Why do you specifically ask for HTTP GET?

Comment: Man... why would someone vote down this question? I see no problem with that!!

Comment: +1 back up.  Perhaps not the best-phrased question for the topic, but it seems to be generating good comments and answers.

Comment: Might want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198462/get-versus-post-in-terms-of-security.

Comment: @Nemo - That question offers no help what-so-ever.

Answer (score 7):

If you have anything worth obscuring then I would suggest going to HTTPS and dumping HTTP.

Typically I would not put anything related to customer, vendor or order identifiers in the query string.  But that is me.

Comment: Yes, thank you.  Do you have any other http 'get' security best practices?

Answer (score 4):

I think you should never obscure GET parameters.

If you need to hide the parameters in the query String at the navigation bar, you should use post.

If you want to prevent sniffers to intercept you GET parameters data, use HTTPS.

Comment: POST is no more secure than GET.

Comment: It´s not about security, its about hiding the parameters from the query string at the navigation bar

Comment: And POST queries can't be bookmarked, indexed directly by google, etc.  Google has an impressive ability to find "hidden" pages.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could expand on what you're trying to accomplish? In general you should avoid putting important things (like login credentials) in a URL. URLs have a habit of "leaking" out.

General advice: set up your robots.txt to prevent Google from indexing any of these pages and make the login tokens (or whatever) one-time use only.

Edit: I would suggest not using weak XOR "encryption." If you're worried about people tampering with the URL parameters then add a secure hash. If you actually need to hide what information the query contains then encrypt it for real, don't roll your own weak algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Never but secure information in a `GET` request. These requests get logged directly by the web server. So, the information is available in plain text format for a 3rd party to review and crack if they wish to do so.

If you need to pass credentials, use a cookie to store the state information and layer everything over SSL.

Comment: In addition to Get requests being logged by the web server, they are also going to be stored in a local browser history.

Comment: very true! plus any transparent proxy sitting in between.

Answer (score 0):

A few come to mind...

- Authentication and Authorization may be needed, depending upon what is being requested.
- How one consumes and uses query parameter data is worth considering.  If the parameter data is used in any manner other than a set selection of options, and if it is coming from an untrusted source potentially, then one may want to validate the parameter values.
- Caution returning error codes.  An attacker can use error codes to determine possible attack vectors by learning the topography of your site: what is returned if the resource either does not exist or the parameters are bad, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use HttpModule in asp.net, which could encrypt HTTP Get values globally -
[HttpModule for query string encryption](http://madskristensen.net/post/HttpModule-for-query-string-encryption.aspx). Also, use SessionId as a key for encryption/description, which makes querystring more secure for each session. However, it's not 100% secure, and I would not recommend it for high security website.

As 'JD' suggested, It's better to use HTTPS to secure communication between server and client. However, client could change parameter value on the browser easily e.g. /showinvoice.aspx?id=1000 to /showinvoice.aspx?id=1001

I suggest to validate each validate each parameter's value on the server-side before executing the page. This would stop executing a request, which is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Use POST if you want more security?

You shouldn't be passing account information in the querystring.

Comment: Ow that is rough, and completely uncalled for.

Comment: It is *absolutely* called for.  In fact a downvote is called for.  The post is an off the cuff remark without reading the entire OP or any other response.

Answer (score 0):

My honest answer is that unless the data is REALLY sensitive (like a password, or credit card number, etc) then whoever coded the "encryption" was probably trying to cover up a lack of proper authentication/authorization in the app.

If for instance you are concerned that if you don't encrypt the "accountId=1" part of the URL then someone will be able to tamper it to "accountId=2" and view someone else's account, then the real flaw in the app is that it doesn't check the ownership of the account before delivering the goods!

Trying to fix this lack of authorization checking with encryption is at best a bandaid. Note that bandaids are sometimes necessary - it may be too hard to do anything else at this point - but we should still recognize it for what it is.