# Best way to log POST data in Apache?

Tags: logging, apache, apache-config

Imagine you have a site API that accepts data in the form of GET requests with parameters, or as POST requests (say, with standard url-encoded, &-separated POST data).  If you want to log and analyze API calls, the GET requests will be easy, because they will be in the apache log.  Is there a simple way to get the POST data in the apache log as well?

(Of course we could log the POST data explicitly in the application, but I'd like to have an configuration-level way that let me not worry about it in code.)

Comment: Related question at ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/questions/51295/logging-http-post-in-apache

Answer (score 43):

Use Apache's [mod_dumpio](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dumpio.html). Be careful for obvious reasons.

Note that mod_dumpio [stops logging binary payloads at the first null character](http://www.skepticism.us/2015/09/apache-module-dumpio-doesnt-dump-null-zero-bytes/). For example a `multipart/form-data` upload of a gzip'd file will probably only show the first few bytes with mod_dumpio.

Also note that Apache might not mention this module in `httpd.conf` even when it's present in the `/modules` folder. Just manually adding `LoadModule` will work fine.

Comment: mod_dumpio doesn't sound like it can be restricted to a specific location context, it's only server-wide

Comment: @JosipRodin should be possible via LogLevel (that can be set also in vhost or dir context). _Additionally, mod_dumpio needs to be configured to LogLevel trace7_

Answer (score 25):

You can install `mod_security` and put in `/etc/modsecurity/modsecurity.conf`:

```
SecRuleEngine On
SecAuditEngine On
SecAuditLog /var/log/apache2/modsec_audit.log
SecRequestBodyAccess on
SecAuditLogParts ABIJDFHZ
```

Comment: modsecurity has Ubuntu packages whereas others do not.

Comment: What others? Like dumpio? It's already included with Apache HTTPD — at least in Ubuntu 16.04. That's why there's no separate package for it. You just need to enable it.

Comment: For `http 2.4` yum package is `mod24_security` and config file location is `/etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_security.conf`

Comment: dumpio looks like it's limited to the first 256 bytes of the body, then truncates the rest.

Comment: Does this log all requests or only such with security violations? Can it be limited to certain URLs, for example if I want to debug only one specific form?

Comment: This example logs all traffic quite extended. At 
https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-%28v2.x%29#SecAuditLog it says "Scope Any" so it should be possible to use this directive within <Location> or <Directory>

Answer (score 16):

You can use `[ModSecurity][1]` to view POST data.

Install on Debian/Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt install libapache2-mod-security2
```

Use the recommended configuration file:

```
$ sudo mv /etc/modsecurity/modsecurity.conf-recommended /etc/modsecurity/modsecurity.conf
```

Reload Apache:

```
$ sudo service apache2 reload
```

---

You will now find your data logged under `/var/log/apache2/modsec_audit.log`

```
$ tail -f /var/log/apache2/modsec_audit.log
--2222229-A--
[23/Nov/2017:11:36:35 +0000] 
--2222229-B--
POST / HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: curl
Host: example.com

--2222229-C--
{"test":"modsecurity"}
```

Comment: The default config logged nothing for me. I had to set
SecRuleEngine On
SecAuditEngine On

Answer (score 13):

Though It's late to answer. This module can do: https://github.com/danghvu/mod_dumpost

Comment: cool! it makes absolutly sense to dump post data for logfile analysis i.e. for things like sql injection attempts.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it in the application, actually. It's still configurable at runtime, depending on your logger system, of course. For example, if you use Apache Log (log4j/cxx) you could configure a dedicated logger for such URLs and then configure it at runtime from an XML file.

Comment: My concern there is that EVERY api handler will have to log the data at the beginning -- easy to forget as you're adding, and at best it's just added boilerplate.

Comment: Any good framework should have pre and post filters, or the equivalent of middleware which will allow you to fire and forget.

Answer (score 2):

Enable mod_dumpio

- for Debian-based OS

  sudo a2enmod dump_io
- for RedHat-based OS

  nothing to do, it is enabled by default

Add mod_dumpio to your virtual host configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  ServerName  localhost

  ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/error.log"
  CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/access.log" combined

  DumpIOInput On
  DumpIOOutput On
  LogLevel dumpio:trace7    
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart Apache

Answer (score 0):

An easier option may be to log the POST data before it gets to the server. For web applications, I use [Burp Proxy](https://portswigger.net/burp/) and set Firefox to use it as an HTTP/S proxy, and then I can watch (and mangle) data 'on the wire' in real time.

For making API requests without a browser, SoapUI is very useful and may show similar info. I would bet that you could probably configure SoapUI to connect through Burp as well (just a guess though).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use mod DumpIO, activate it, and load from your Apache Log Conf. Define log name as postdata name, and load to AccessLog statement

> #AccessLog /path/to/your/log/abc.access.log combine

> AccessLog /path/to/your/log/abc.access.log postdata

Comment: This does not work. AccessLog is not an Apache config directive, "postdata" is not defined anywhere, DumpIO always seems to default to "/var/log/apache2/error.log" even if you specify ErrorLog to point elsewhere

Answer (score -2):

You can also use the built-in forensic log feature.

Comment: I don't see any to ask mod_log_forensic to log POST data. Am I missing something?

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_forensic.html#forensiclog indicates this module can only be as granular as a virtual host

Comment: forensic log doesn't log content