# Apache log tracking

Tags: php, apache

I created a web page hosted on apache2.2.

Currently, I get only the pages name in the Apache access logs (eg: `home.php`, `result.php`, `logout.php` that are accessed in the webpage).

How can I track the options selected by the user in the Apache logs?

E.g.: If there are 2 radio buttons & one text box, I would like to track the radio button values & the text box values in the Apache logs.

Answer (score 1):

Apache logs will only show data submitted via GET, since it becomes part of the URL (which gets logged).

If your HTML form is submitted with the POST method, then the values will not appear in the Apache logs.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Best way to log POST data in Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/989967) there is ["mod_dumpio"](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dumpio.html) and similar modules, but they will generally have some issues, and be incredibly verbose.

If you want finer-grain logging of things that you choose, then a logging library (such as MonoLog) can usually be easily included and then you will have full control as to what and where you log.