# Apache logging format to record data sent by user to server in the access log

Tags: apache, logging

I want to record the data sent by the user to server in apache access log but i'm not able  to find the format for this task.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html

This has no information which i want to achieve.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Please define "data sent by user". Also, do you really use Apache 1.3? That's super old.

Comment: @Capsule "data sent by user " --> for example if a user is making post request then how much data he is sending to server ,also updated the url with latest apache version

Comment: My understanding is this already answers your question: https://serverfault.com/questions/524846/combined-log-format-post-size

Comment: If you want to log the actual data, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989967/best-way-to-log-post-data-in-apache