# Does hosting/server save $_POST data, like $_GET access data

Tags: post

in `/logs/access` there is always stored all access requests of website, i.e.

```
2017/02/03 17:51:22 HTTP 200 http://yoursite.com/url/  ............
2017/02/03 17:51:27 HTTP 200 http://yoursite.com/smth/ ............
```

and so on.

Does server also store $_POST data somewhere? at least, for the last day?

Comment: It sounds like you're lost important data due to a programming error. Next time plan ahead and figure out how to recover from such errors. See also [Best way to log POST data in Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989967/best-way-to-log-post-data-in-apache).

Comment: Not by default - you've not specified your system info but this question may be relevant - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989967/best-way-to-log-post-data-in-apache

Comment: @CodeCaster yes, i've lost important data of transaction..

Comment: @T.Todua Well, ask your hoster if he logs the data. He's the only one who can tell you that.

Comment: thanks, i'll try..

Answer (score 4):

Usually not unless it is set up explicitly to do that. That is also one of the reasons why login forms should be sent via POST and not GET.

Comment: 1) then how login forms should be sent? encrypted by Javascript /decrypted by PHP/  or..?

2) i still believe hostings save that data...

Comment: What is your concern? If you don't trust your hoster host the site on your own server. No matter what kind of encryption/decryption scheme you implemented, unless you transfer the data off the server before decryption your hoster can access it.

Comment: i didt say that i dont trust them, i said that they probably save that, and i will try to contact them.