# Log GET requests and querystring in PHP (Apache)

Tags: php, apache, api, logging, get

We have a PHP application running on Apache and want to log all API requests (GET + parameters).

I have seen this post [Best way to log POST data in Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989967/best-way-to-log-post-data-in-apache) where it says "the GET requests will be easy, because they will be in the apache log".

However, when I look in our logs, they are not there. What server log settings do I need to have to record GET requests + querystring? No mention of how to do this in https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html

Comment: From the [Apache Documentation -> Access log](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html#accesslog): "The server access log records all requests processed by the server." It explicitly contains an example where a GET request is logged (paragraph 8) Maybe you could compare the settings explained there with yours to see if your server logs incoming requests

Answer (score 1):

The GET request are logged in the access log file. Read the documentation you provided, especially the `Access Log` part is important.
Your Apache host should be configured with something like:

```
LogLevel        info
ErrorLog        "/private/var/log/apache2/{hostname}-error.log"
CustomLog       "/private/var/log/apache2/{hostname}-access.log" combined
```

GET requests can then be found in `/private/var/log/apache2/{hostname}-access.log`

An easy and quick way to do this for debugging purposes is to write a function that logs the POST data.

```
function logPost() {
    if (isset($_POST && !empty($_POST) {
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
            error_log('=== _POST REQUEST ===');
            error_log('_POST: '.$key.' => '.$value);
        }
        // OR serialise the data but this is less readable
        error_log('=== _POST REQUEST ===');
        error_log(serialise($_POST));
    }
}
```

POST requests can then be found in `/private/var/log/apache2/{hostname}-error.log`

Comment: Just to be clear, do you replace {hostname} with the hostname or is it a variable that is automatically replaced.

Comment: Yes manually replace it with your hostname or use an ENV variable with the name if you have one

Comment: Just to be clear and I may have to rewrite the question - I am looking to log GET requests made to another server NOT GET requests on this server. Will this still work?

Comment: Ah, that would have been good to make more clear in the question. Apache can only log requests made TO it, not from it. At least as far a i know

Comment: If you where to query your own server `http://host.example/index.php?query=test_api` this would be logged by Apache. If you make a request from inside php `header(...)` for example, that will not be logged