# GET vs. POST does it really really matter?

Tags: asp.net, http

Ok, I know the difference in purpose.  GET is to get some data. Make a request and get data back.  POST should be used for CRUD operations other than read I believe.  But when it comes down to it, does the server really care if it's receiving a GET vs. POST in the end?

Comment: Reading the HTTP 1.1 spec might help you- http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Comment: I gotta wonder... Why does this question have 19 answers, about 40 votes on the answers, and only one Up-Vote on the question (mine).  Its a good question!  Are people just lazy about up-voting questions?

Comment: @abelenky - I had run out of votes to give yesterday, here's +1 for today

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is either GET or POST more secure than the other?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198462/is-either-get-or-post-more-secure-than-the-other)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you're the one writing the server software (presumably), then it cares if you tell it to care. If you handle POST and GET data identically, then no, it doesn't.

However, the browser definitely cares. Refreshing or clicking back to a page you got as a response to a POST pops up the little "Are you sure you want to submit data again" prompt, for example.

Comment: More importantly, you can use the Post/Redirect/Get pattern to prevent people from accidentally redoing actions.

Comment: That can be worked around, though, if your code that handles the POST request never displays anything itself but instead redirects to a page that does. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: Of course. And that is pretty much my point. From the browser's point of view, it matters whether you submit data via a POST or GET, and so they should be handled differently by the server. I wouldn't call it a "workaround" though, since that implies that the browser's behavior is an error. It works this way for a perfectly good reason, and the "workaround" is a perfectly logical way to handle it.

Answer (score 16):

According to the HTTP RFC, GET should not have any side-effects, while POST may have side-effects.

The most basic example of this is that GET is not appropriate for anything like a purchase-transaction or posting an article to a blog, while POST is appropriate for actions-that-have-consequences.

By the RFC, you can hold a user responsible for actions done by POST (such as a purchase), but not for GET actions.  'Bots always use GET for this reason.

From the [RFC 2616, 9.1.1](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt#9.1.1):

> **9.1.1 Safe Methods**
>
> Implementors should be aware that the
>   software represents the user in
>   their interactions over the Internet,
>   and should be careful to allow    the
>   user to be aware of any actions they
>   might take which may have an
>   unexpected significance to themselves
>   or others.
>
> In particular, the convention has
>   been established that the GET and
>   HEAD methods SHOULD NOT have the
>   significance of taking an action
>   other than retrieval. These methods
>   ought to be considered "safe".    This
>   allows user agents to represent other
>   methods, such as POST, PUT    and
>   DELETE, in a special way, so that the
>   user is made aware of the    fact that
>   a possibly unsafe action is being
>   requested.
>
> Naturally, it is not possible to
>   ensure that the server does not
>   generate side-effects as a result of
>   performing a GET request; in    fact,
>   some dynamic resources consider that a
>   feature. The important    distinction
>   here is that the user did not request
>   the side-effects,    so therefore
>   cannot be held accountable for them.

Answer (score 13):

It does if a search engine is crawling the page, since they will be making GET requests but not POST. Say you have a link on your page:

```
http://www.example.com/items.aspx?id=5&mode=delete
```

Without some sort of authorization check performed before the delete, it's possible that Googlebot could [come in and delete items](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_Spider_of_Doom.aspx) from your page.

Comment: Excellent find Brian, I was looking for that exact article to link to!

Comment: Even with authorization, attackers can send an email with <img src="http://www.example.com/items.aspx?id=5&mode=delete
"> to somebody who is already logged in.

Comment: @Paco:  If your browser loads that img, it will use GET.  The web-server should NOT do actions such as "delete" based on a GET-request for exactly this reason.  It is the web-server's responsibility to enforce that serious actions only happen through POST requests.

Comment: @Paco - and that's precisely why you should never do it this way :)

Answer (score 4):

GET has data limit restrictions based on the sending browser:

The spec for URL length does not dictate a minimum or maximum URL length, but implementation varies by browser. On Windows: Opera supports ~4050 characters, IE 4.0+ supports exactly 2083 characters, Netscape 3 -> 4.78 support up to 8192 characters before causing errors on shut-down, and Netscape 6 supports ~2000 before causing errors on start-up

Comment: There can also be a limit on GET requests on the server-side. For example Apache has a default limit set to [8190 bytes](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestline)

Answer (score 2):

If you use a GET request to alter back-end state, you run the risk of bad things happening if a webcrawler of some kind traverses your site. Back when wikis first became popular, there were horror stories of whole sites being deleted because the "delete page" function was implemented as a GET request, with disastrous results when the Googlebot came knocking...

Answer (score 2):

"Use GET if: The interaction is more like a question (i.e., it is a safe operation such as a query, read operation, or lookup)."

"Use POST if: The interaction is more like an order, or the interaction changes the state of the resource in a way that the user would perceive (e.g., a subscription to a service), or the user be held accountable for the results of the interaction."

[source](http://www.davidpirek.com/blog.aspx?n=AJAX-post-vs.-AJAX-GET:-When-should-you-use-get-and-when-POST?)

Answer (score 2):

By HTTP specifications, GET is safe and idempotent and POST is neither.  What this means is that a GET request can be repeated multiple times without causing side effects.

Even if your server doesn't care (and this is unlikely), there may be intermediate agents between your client and the server, all of whom have this expectation.  For example proxies to cache data at your ISP or other providers for improved performance.  THe same expectation is true for accelerators, for example, a prefetching plugin for your browser.

Thus a GET request can be cached (based on certain parameters), and if it fails, it can be automatically repeated without any expecation of harmful effects.  So, really your server should strive to fulfill this contract.

On the other hand, POST is not safe, not idempotent and every agent knows not to cache the results of a POST request, or retry a POST request automatically.  So, for example, a credit card transaction would never, ever be a GET request (you don't want accounts being debited multiple times because of network errors, etc).

That's a very basic take on this.  For more information, you might consider the "RESTful Web Services" book by Ruby and Richardson (O'Reilly press).

For a quick take on the topic of REST, consider this post:

http://www.25hoursaday.com/weblog/2008/08/17/ExplainingRESTToDamienKatz.aspx

The funny thing is that most people debate the merits of PUT v POST.  The GET v POST issue is, and always has been, very well settled.  Ignore it at your own peril.

Answer (score 2):

You be aware of a few subtle security differences. See my question

> [GET versus POST in terms of security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198462/get-versus-post-in-terms-of-security)

Essentially the important thing to remember is that GET will go into the browser history and will be transmitted through proxies in plain text, so you don't want any sensitive information, like a password in a GET.

Obvious maybe, but worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

Should the user be able to bookmark the resulting page? Another thing to think about is some browsers/servers incorrectly limit the GET URI length.

**Edit:** corrected char length restriction note - thanks ars!

Comment: jbruce211:  This is a limit based on implementations (for example browsers or http servers).  It is not a limit intrinsic to GET per the HTTP spec.  

From the spec:  "The HTTP protocol does not place any a priori limit on the length of a URI. Servers MUST be able to handle the URI of any resource they serve, and SHOULD be able to handle URIs of unbounded length if they provide GET-based forms that could generate such URIs."  http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html

Answer (score 1):

GET has limitations on the browser side.  For instance, [some browsers](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;en-us;q208427) limit the length of GET requests.

Answer (score 1):

I think a more appropriate answer, is you can pretty much do the same things with both.  It is not so much a matter of preference, however, but a matter of *correct usage*.  I would recommend you use you GETs and POSTs how they were **intended** to be used.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, no. All GET does is post the stuff in the first line of the HTTP request, and POST posts stuff in the body.

However, how the "web infrastructure" treats the differences makes a world of difference. We could write a whole book about it. However, I'll give you some "best practises":

Use "POST" for when your HTTP request would change something "concrete" inside the web server. Ie, you're editing a page, making a new record, and so on. POSTS are less likely to be cached, or treated as something that's "repeatable without side-effects"

Use "GET" for when you want to "look at an object". Now, such a look might change something "behind the scenes" in terms of caching or record keeping, but it shouldn't change anything "substantial". Ie, I could repeat my GET over and over and nothing bad would happen, except for inflated hit counts. GETs should be easily bookmarkable, so a user can go back to that same object later on.

The parameters to the GET (the stuff after the ?, traditionally) should be considered "attributes to the view" or "what to view" and so on. Again, it shouldn't actually change anything: use POST for that.

And, a final word, when you POST something (for example, you're creating a new comment), have the processing for the post issue a 302 to "redirect" the user to a new URL that views that object. Ie, a POST processes the information, then redirects the browser to a GET statement to view the new state. Displaying information as a result of a POST can also cause problems. Doing the redirection is often used, and makes things work better.

Comment: "Technically, no."  This is a little strange.  I mean, everything we programmers do is ones and zeros at the end of the day, so "technically", there's no difference between much of anything!  The authoritative reference here is the HTTP spec (rfc 2616) which does make a technical distinction in section 9.

Comment: ars: unfortunately, what the HTTP spec doesn't mention is what applications (eg, the web server, cgi scripts, web application frameworks) DO with that information. This can't be gleaned from the HTTP spec. So, according to the spec, the only difference is how the information is send to the HTTP server. Depending on the receiver (the program that receives the data) there could be ZERO difference between GET and POST, or a world of difference.

So, my answer is "if you do it this way, you will run into fewer problems than if you do it any other way".

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the software at the server end. Some libraries, like CGI.pm in perl handles both by default. But there are situations where you more or less have to use POST instead of GET, at least for pushing data to the server. Large amounts of data (where the corresponding GET url would become too long), binary data (to avoid lots of encoding/decoding trouble), multipart files, non-parsed headers (for continuous updates pre-AJAX style...) and similar.

Answer (score 0):

The server technically couldn't care one way or the other about what kind of request it receives. It will blindly execute any request coming across the wire.

Which is the problem. If you have an action that destroys or modifies data in a `GET` action, Google will tear your site up as it crawls through indexing.

Answer (score 0):

The server usually doesn't care.  But it's mostly for following good practices, as you mentioned.  The client side also matter - as mentioned you cannot bookmark a POST'd page usually, and some browsers have limits on the length of the URL for really long GET queries.

Answer (score 0):

Since GET is intended for specifying resource you wanna get, depending on exact software on the server side, the web server (or the load balancer in front of it) may have a size limit on GET requests to prevent Denial Of Service attacks...

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that browsers may cache GET requests but will generally not cache POST requests.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does matter. GET and POST are quite different, really.

You are right in that normally, GET is for "getting" data from the server and displaying a page, while POST is for "posting" data back to the server. Internally, your scripts get the same data whether it's GET or POST, so no, the server doesn't really care.

The main difference is GET parameters are specified in URLs, while POST is not. This is why POST is used for signup and login forms - you don't want your password in a URL. Similarly, if you're viewing different pages or displaying a specific view of some data, you normally want a unique URL.

Comment: Not passing your password in a URL is no kind of security, and no way to go through life, son. (grin).  If you use plain-text (HTTP vs. HTTPS), your password is visible whether its POST or GET.

Comment: I never said POST was more secure at all, I said you don't want your password in a URL. What happens if a user posts that URL on a forum or something?

Answer (score 0):

It really does matter. I have gathered like 11 things you should know abut them.

[11 things you should know about GET vs POST](http://%20https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/get-vs-post-are-you-confident-about-the-differences-189562fac0a7)

Answer (score -1):

No, they shouldn't except for @jbruce2112 answer and uploading files require POST.