# passing CSRF credentials as url parameters?

Tags: django, iframe, security, csrf

How do you handle csrf credentials sent to django as url parameters?

I ask because that is, evidently, [the only way to submit a file upload via a form in an iFrame](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/pull/148#issuecomment-4251262).

Most online examples show to pass csrf credentials as headers,

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrfToken );
```

but this is not an option for iFrame transport in ie/opera.

I can use [`csrf_exempt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#edge-cases), but this leaves my site vulnerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create some middleware that takes `csrf_token` from the GET params and places it on the request before `CsrfViewMiddleware` attempts to validate

```
class CsrfGetParamMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        request.META['HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN'] = request.GET.get('csrf_token')
        return None
```

Place this middleware above the `CsrfViewMiddleware`

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'CsrfGetParamMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
)
```

This save you from validating it yourself or subclassing `CsrfViewMiddleware`

Comment: v interesting idea, but are there security precautions that need to be taken into account using csrf as a url parameter in the 1st place?

Comment: TBH I'm not sure, according to http://stackoverflow.com/a/198473/682968 GET and POST have the same level of security so its really no different to POSTing a form 'normally'.  Also the csrf token is freely available in the page source as well so anyone could read it there too.

Comment: @rockingskier: The answer you are referring to was accepted, but gained more than 3 times fewer votes than some other answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1744404/548696), not without a reason.

Comment: @Tadeck, so it did, thanks for pointing to the better answer.