# Why are query strings sent in the URL of a GET request and sent in the body of POST requests?

Tags: http, post, web, get, query-string

GET:

```
GET /blog/?name1=value1&name2=value2 HTTP/1.1
Host: website.com
```

POST:

```
POST /blog/ HTTP/1.1
Host: website.com
name1=value1&name2=value2
```

I don't see why there should be a difference.

Comment: `name1=value1&name2=value2` in your POST example _is not_ a Query String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GET is supposed to be used for bookmark-able pages or repeatable searches; so the URL stores the query data so it can be used repeatedly by the browser.

POST, on the other hand, is for one-time requests containing sensitive information or information that might be too long for a query string. The data isn't supposed to be saved like in a GET request, so it is stored in the body.

You might also want to see this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/198473/436524

Answer (score 0):

It's a result of how form submission is defined for HTML forms. It has nothing to do with HTTP itself.