# Is just SSL certificate is secure enough to protect HTTP POST?

Tags: security, ssl, https, http-post, ssl-certificate

I have send data server to server. 
Without speak about network security, do I have to use other methods to protect it? I think about token system for example, or the certificate is enough?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is either GET or POST more secure than the other?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198462/is-either-get-or-post-more-secure-than-the-other)

Comment: Thanks @jww but it's not my question, I know the difference with GET and POST, I already saw this post and check in for my issue, I didn't found anything. I look for kind of "Best practices" to secure my posted data. I'm novice for this, I use a web service to send my data but I don't know how protect it properly

Comment: See the Community Wiki answer and the section titled, *So what should I do?*. The Community Wiki answer is about half way down the page with 318 upvotes. If you have a more specific question, then you should probably open another question.