# Security using Django 1.10 + AJAX without any HTML form

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, security

I make a POST request via AJAX without HTML form.
Are there any security issues?
Why is there no csrf error? Because I do not send any csrf data and csrf is enabled in django?

toggle-status.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#switch-status").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/account/switches/',
        data: {'toggle': 'status'}
    });
    });
});
```

view.py

```
@login_required
def switches(request):
    toggle = request.GET.get('toggle', None)
    current_user = request.user
    update = Switches.objects.get(owner=current_user)
    if toggle == 'status':
    if update.status is True:
        update.status = False
    else:
        update.status = True
    update.save()
    return HttpResponse('')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [default method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) of the `ajax` function is a `GET` one, not a `POST`. So, doing a:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/account/switches/',
    data: {'toggle': 'status'}
});
```

implies that an ajax `GET` is made. So, you're not doing a `POST` request.

If you want a `POST` request, do it like this:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/account/switches/',
    data: {'toggle': 'status'}
});
```

Of course you have to include the CSRF token then, since it will fail if you try to `POST` without including one. Look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/) how to acomplish that.

Comment: Thank you. Are there any other security issues with GET?

Comment: As long as you do not pass any sensitive data through this method then no, there are no security issues. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198462/is-either-get-or-post-more-secure-than-the-other) or [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33837/get-vs-post-which-is-more-secure) for more.

Comment: @nik_m can you talk? :)

Comment: @nik_m can you follow me on twitter so i can write you there next time, trying to get to you throw stack is a bit hard, i can't chat with you unless you follow me aswell