# How to Check Information received via a url and returning response as URL too?

Tags: javascript, php, url, redirect, authentication

I want to check information received via a url like
http://www.example.com/login?name=john&password=1234

And return information as url by redirecting it to
If it is right then- http://www.example.com/right

If it is wrong then - /false

Comment: Use the Header location. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php#768472

Comment: what is right and wrong? any query string passed in URL ?

Comment: Please do not send sensitive information in the URL, always use `POST` for such kind of requests and pass the information in the request body. See this answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1744404/5648904)

Comment: Security doesn't matter , also the url will not be visible to user, it will run in background...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the header function to redirect the user. The header function allows sending http headers back to the user. For example `header("Location: " . $url)`. Your script should not send output before calling the header function. See this link: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_header.asp