# For Login GET or POST?

Tags: php, mysql, http, authentication, get

I want to know which HTTP method i use for developing a login API, GET or POST ?.
I have developed my login API in PHP using post method, but my BOSS say that, why you use POST method instead of GET method.

Answer (score 19):

Always `POST`, and **preferably** with SSL (as in: `https://...`). Because the parameters in `GET` get stored all over the place for caching reasons.

So, if you boss needs a reason: **security**.

---

There is a REST-related reason: the `GET` queries first of all are expected to be aggressively cached, because they do not alter the server state of data. The `POST` requests instead are expected to never be cached, because the alter the state of server and (unlike `PUT` request), there is no expectation for calling multiple `POST` request to return the same response and leave the server in the same state.

For example: if you send 5 login request, that fail, the 6th one can return *"your IP has been blocked for 30 min"* as a response.

Answer (score 5):

Use POST. With GET the parameters are in the URL, which is very insecure. While https (you are using https, right?) should encrypt everything end-to-end, with GET the parameters will be in plain text in log files and in the user's browser (until the next page is loaded or redirected).

Answer (score -2):

there really little difference between POST and GET from security point of view, more important using HTTPS, and properly tuned server

Comment: No. GET parameters are passed via URL and is visible.

Comment: Nothig is visible if request ajaxed, and this API may be not for browsers, then GET preffered since it simple

Comment: I can't see why this answer was downvoted. If anything to get downvoted for, would be a tad low-quality. Other than that, whoever did downvote it, should read [Is either GET or POST more secure than the other?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198462/is-either-get-or-post-more-secure-than-the-other)

Comment: Visible in access logs like this. `127.0.0.1 - - [14/May/2017:20:16:28 +0530] "GET /phpmyadmin/index.php?ajax_request=1&recent_table=1&token=8269`

Comment: Also I didn't down vote.

Comment: access logs must be protected by administrator

Comment: *"it does not matter POST or GET, more important using HTTPS"* - @acr You are right to a certain extent. The reason for the person's downvote could have been because you seem to be stating that using POST or GET through a regular `http:` call that it doesn't matter; it does. Through an `https:` call, then that's a different story. You should edit your answer and to be a better answer. Just trying to help you out here.

Comment: php coder add wrong answer about get cahing, how will they complain?

Comment: Yes. The admin must protect logs. But even in that context POST is little more secure as it is neither logged nor cached.

Comment: difference really little, and depend on server and server settings, server can be set for get secure