# Monogame- Should my login be a POST or a GET

Tags: .net, .net-core, request, xna, monogame

Since I will not be creating a session and simply just getting the user with the specified username and password should I use GET instead of POST?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you mean by "just getting the user with the specified username and password" or what you're trying to do at the game end?

Answer (score 4):

Does the endpoint needs to receive any sensitive data from your request?

If yes, I would strongly recommend to use POST method in this case.

The first reason for that is that GET method, in case you are providing some data (e.g: username, password) will contain it in the query string. However, post will put it to the body of your request.

Also some differences to be aware of:

- GET requests can be cached
- GET requests remain in the browser history
- GET requests can be bookmarked

Some similar question you can see here [For Login GET or POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43965316/for-login-get-or-post)