# Do I need to verify a login request is POST when I'm using request.form.get()

Tags: python, authentication, flask, flask-login

Lots of code I've seen online for login routing in Flask looks like this,

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        password = request.form.get('password')
        if password == "pass":
            #login
            return redirect('/index')
    return render_template(login.html)
```

for

```
<form action='/login' method='POST'>
    <input type='password' id="pass' name='pass'>
    <input type='submit' value='Login'>
</form>
```

However the way I first wrote it was,

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    password = request.form.get('password')
    if password == "pass":
        #login
        return redirect('/index')
    return render_template(login.html)
```

i.e., not first checking the request is a POST. Both work, but from what I've read online, the former is considered more secure - can someone tell me why?

If we had something like

```
password = request.args.get('password')
```

Then I can see why not checking the request is a POST could be less secure, because we could login with the URL,

```
/login?password=pass
```

Which shows the password in the URL and is easier to brute force. But it is my understanding

```
request.forms.get('password')
```

cannot be manipulated through URLs in the same way. So why is checking for POST better/safer?

Comment: The contents of URLs including their parameters are not treated in the same way as the contents of the request body in certain network setups (proxies performing SSL termination in certain environments come to mind - their logging typically would include the full URL, thereby exposing your credentials in plaintext). Less important but it doesn’t make sense to allow `GET` for logging in when you read [the HTTP spec explaining what `GET`’s intended use is.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#GET)

Comment: Duplicate [Is either GET or POST more secure than the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198462/is-either-get-or-post-more-secure-than-the-other)

Comment: In a GET request, surely `request.form` will be empty, because no form was actually submitted?

Comment: Yes @JohnGordon: it equals None on the first GET request -> no login -> so you execute `render_template('login.html')` -> then you get a POST request and login can happen (i've updated my post to show this). Since you can't change request.form from the URL in the same way as request.args, I don't know how you could login with a GET request.

Comment: Putting the password in the URL doesn't make it any easier to brute force. You still have to try every possible password. However, if someone is looking at your screen it makes it easy for them to see your password, which is not a good idea. You can solve this by returning a redirect.

Comment: @Barmar it would make it easier to brute force if you, say, needed to solve a captcha before clicking submit on the form, no? Either way my whole point is you don't get passwords in the URL even with my second snippet of Flask code above, which doesn't check if it's a POST (thus my question, why do people check). Not sure what you mean by returning a redirect.

Comment: I think *technically* you can submit form data even with GET. It's just uncommon and often not supported by tools and frameworks. Flask (or werkzeug, internally) will probably also only ever fill the `request.form` object with data sent through the request body if the method is POST, so no need to check that twice. IMHO: Security wise it doesn't matter at all here. It would matter for the client, proxies, and logging if passwords were sent in the url, but that's all happened way before your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that request.form will never contain any data for a get request and that in your specific example checking that it is a post request is unnecessary and does not improve security. The problem with not checking the request type is that your code cannot otherwise differentiate between the initial get request to display the form in the first place and the user submitting an empty form where you might want to display an error message to help them understand what they need to do. Also when using a form to edit data, checking the request type is necessary to differentiate between the initial data that you supply to the user and their edited data. Seeing as the request type check is necessary in the vast majority of cases it is standard practice to always include it but you can safely omit it in your very specific case.

Answer (score 0):

If you use POST request then the form data will be sent to the request body rather than as a part of the URL, this helps in keeping the user info. secure cause it's not visible in address bar or in server logs.

And also, while using POST request you can provide Cross-Site Request Forgery(CSRF) token to defend against CSRF attacks, server verifies to ensure that request is legit. That's why using it is more secure, and I in your way, the method attribute don't have any use so removing it won't change anything, but you should always check for POST request during these types of processes.

Comment: The question wasn't about how the client should send data, but how the server should process it, and if using `flask.request.form` is always "safe" there even if not checking for the request verb first.

Comment: Got it, Thanks.